# disable a hidden control in sharepoint using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have hidden a sharepoint yes/no filed using jquery. When i am logged in as another user i want to directly disable the hidden field. Somehow unless i show it first , i am not able to disable it.

This works : **this field is hidden with jquery**

```
$("nobr:contains('Extend This Contract ?')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').show(); $("input[Title='Extend This Contract ?']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

This does not

```
$("input[Title='Extend This Contract ?']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Any workarounds for this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a html snippet so we know the context?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `prop` instead of `attr`:

```
$("input[Title='Extend This Contract ?']").prop("disabled", true);
```